# Python: Create csv from json/dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have the following data that needs to be transformed into a csv:

```json
 "tfeOrganizations": [
        {
            "org": "MyOrg1",
            "org_admins": [
                "foo@bar.com", "foo2@bar2.com"
            ],
            "org_viewers": [
                "foo3@bar3.com","foo4@bar4.com"
            ],
            "teams": {
                "genericresources-admins": {
                    "ci_cd_token_regenerate": False,
                    "members": ["firstUser@test.com", "secondUser@test.com"],
                    "workspaces": [
                        [
                            "genericresources-dev",
                            "write"
                        ],
                        [
                            "genericresources-qa",
                            "write"
                        ],
                        [
                            "genericresources-prod",
                            "write"
                        ]
                    ]
                 },
                 "genericresources-contributors": {
                    "ci_cd_token_regenerate": False,
                    "members": ["thirdUser@test.com", "forthUser@test.com", "fithUser@test.com"],
                    "workspaces": [
                        [
                            "genericresources-dev",
                            "write"
                        ],
                        [
                            "genericresources-qa",
                            "write"
                        ],
                        [
                            "genericresources-prod",
                            "plan"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "workspaces": [
                "genericresources-dev",
                "genericresources-qa",
                "genericresources-prod"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The result should be something like this whereas the header is built dynamically based on the longest array for the members across all organisations.

```
organisation,workspace,org_admin1,org_admin2,org_viewer1,org_viewer2,member1,member2,member3,...

MyOrg1,genericresources-dev,foo@bar.com,foo2@bar2.com,foo3@bar3.com,foo4@bar4.com,firstUser@test,sendUser@test.com,...

MyOrg1,genericresources-qa,foo@bar.com,foo2@bar2.com,foo3@bar3.com,foo4@bar4.com,firstUser@test,sendUser@test.com,...

MyOrg1,genericresources-prod,foo@bar.com,foo2@bar2.com,foo3@bar3.com,foo4@bar4.com,firstUser@test,sendUser@test.com,...
```

Currently I do not how to tackle this problem.

Comment: I don't think having a dynamic number of pivoted columns is going to be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create with pandas

example

```
import pandas as pd

# access your json file
your_json = data['tfeOrganizations']


data_frame = pd.DataFrame(your_json)


data_frame.to_csv('result.csv',data_frame)
```